# Setting override redirect for Gtk window leads to segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, gtk

I am trying to create an application in which I need to draw on a transparent window which stays above all other windows and invisible to the window manager, hence trying to set the override redirect of a window to true .But setting the override redirect for a GdkWindow causes segmentation fault.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void activate(GtkApplication *app) {

    GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    GdkWindow *gdk_window = gtk_widget_get_window(window);
    gdk_window_set_override_redirect(gdk_window, TRUE);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new("com.github.application.name",
                          G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);

    int status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref(app);

    return status;
}
```

compiling with gcc using

```
gcc -o out main.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

what am I missing here? any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`gtk_widget_get_window()`](https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/gtk/gtk3/method.Widget.get_window.html) can return NULL. The reason your code is segfaulting is probably because you're calling `gdk_window_set_override_redirect()` on a NULL pointer.

For the underlying reason why `gtk_widget_get_window()` can return NULL: a GdkWindow maps to the concept of a surface; in X11 this is called an XWindow, hence the name. To let the compositor show your surface/XWindow, you have to explicitly *map* it.

GTK does the mapping operation the moment the `GtkWindow` widget is told to show itself (ie when you call [`gtk_window_present()`](https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/gtk/gtk3/method.Window.present.html) or `gtk_widget_show()`). Once it actually associates with an underlying `GdkWindow`, it will emit the "realize" signal to which you can connect to .

So, in other words, you can either:

- Call `gdk_window_set_override_redirect();` *after* showing the window
- Connect to the ["realize"](https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/gtk/gtk3/signal.Widget.realize.html) signal of your `window` variable, and call `gdk_window_set_override_redirect();` inside the callback

Answer (score 1):

Your code fails because `gdk_window` is `NULL`.

You can ask the window to be created with `gtk_window_present`:

```c
void activate(GtkApplication *app) {

    GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    GdkWindow *gdk_window = gtk_widget_get_window(window);

    gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW(window));

    gdk_window_set_override_redirect(gdk_window, TRUE);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah `gdk_window` was `NULL` and using `gtk_window_present` worked. Thanks.